# ASP.Net Bootstrap Template

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Asp.net and bootstrap. I want to implement an Asp.net project using a bootstrap template such as [one of these](https://colorlib.com/wp/free-bootstrap-admin-dashboard-templates/).

My project uses C# as the backend code. The issue is I do not know hot to manipulate the template from code. When I import it into my project, it imports as .html files. How do I go about seetting this up properly and manipulating the dashboard from C#? As an example, how would I get the  Total Users on [this](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html) template from my database?

Any direction, tutorial links, etc would be appreciated.

Comment: "**Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow** as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: I think I asked a fair question, as I was just looking for some direction. I believe that's a little different than seeking random opinions

Comment: You can search for info based on .net mvc web development. I used that template in one of my mvc projects and it was very easy to integrate it.

Comment: @Hackerman. I am using web forms, is that a problem?

Comment: Most bootstrap stuff is CSS, and you just have to include the small jquery.js library and the small bootstrap.js. Once done, then most bootstrap stuff should work just fine. I mean, vs2013 by "default" includes and uses the bootstrap framework when you create a web project. I currently use bootstrap with vs2013 and it works just fine.  So it not really the HTML that drives the magic of bootstrap - but simply including jquery and the bootstrap.js in that given page. (and that includes asp.net forms. So you can import or cut + paste in the HTML, but the jquery + bootstrap java does the magic.

Answer (score 0):

*There is not a simple and easy way to mix a bootstrap dashboard template with a Asp.net project! On the other hand your question is not a programming problem, you want a tutorial so your question has not a simple answer in stackoverflow and [is not a good question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question).*

Anyway if you are a web programmer:

1. You should read the template documents first.
2. It has some resources include `css` `js` and `images`, so move them to appropriate folders in your projects and refference them in your base layout file of your project.
3. Test it and solve any `js` and `css` errors in a browser such as chrome.
4. Now move the html layout of the template to the project layout page.
5. Go to step 3
6. Other steps are advanced like mixing asp.net codes with them and using bundles

> Note: in your project is a `ASP.NET MVC` project your layout file is
>   inside `Views>Shared` folder.